# Finding the eigenvalues of the matrix, can't get the correct result

Tags: java

There is a code in which the matrix class is implemented, for the convenience of working with operations, there are multiplication functions, differences. The eigenvalue of the matrix is found by the formula det(A - LAMBDA * E), where A is the given matrix, LAMBDA is the desired eigenvalue, E is the unit matrix. The value is found using the function "FindingAnEigenValue" written by me, in which the search goes through all the values with a certain step. The problem is that the value is not found

Body:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Инициализируем переменные
        Matrix _Matrix = new Matrix(3);
        Matrix _DefaultMatrix = new Matrix(3);
        Matrix _SingleMatrix = new Matrix(3);

        // Задаем переменные матрицы
        _Matrix.setMatrixElem();
        _DefaultMatrix = _Matrix;

        //Находим собственное значение
        _Matrix.FindingAnEigenValue(_Matrix,_SingleMatrix, _DefaultMatrix);

    }
}
```

Class:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Matrix {
    public Scanner _Scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    private double MatrixDeterminant;
    private int MatrixSize;
    private double[][] MatrixElem;
    private double[][] MatrixToOperation;
    private double EigenValue;
    private double Lymbda;
    Matrix(int MatrixSize){
        this.MatrixSize = MatrixSize;
        MatrixElem = new double[MatrixSize][MatrixSize];
        MatrixToOperation = new double[MatrixSize][MatrixSize];

    }
    public void setMatrixElem(){

        for (int i=0;i<MatrixSize;i++){
            for (int j=0;j<MatrixSize;j++){
                MatrixElem[i][j] = _Scanner.nextDouble();
            }
        }

    }
    public void getMatrixElem(){
        System.out.println("Матрица имеет вид: ");
        for (int i=0;i<MatrixSize;i++){
            for (int j=0;j<MatrixSize;j++){
                System.out.print(MatrixElem[i][j] + " ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
    public void MultiplyToConst(double Lym){
        for (int i=0;i<MatrixSize;i++){
            for (int j=0;j<MatrixSize;j++){
                MatrixElem[i][j] *=Lym;
            }
        }
    }
    public void MatrixSum(Matrix B){
        this.MatrixToOperation = B.MatrixElem;
        for (int i=0;i<MatrixSize;i++){
            for (int j=0;j<MatrixSize;j++){
                MatrixElem[i][j] += MatrixToOperation[i][j];
            }
        }
    }
    public void MatrixDiff(Matrix B){
        this.MatrixToOperation = B.MatrixElem;
        for (int i=0;i<MatrixSize;i++){
            for (int j=0;j<MatrixSize;j++){
                MatrixElem[i][j] -= MatrixToOperation[i][j];
            }
        }
    }
    public void MatrixMultiply(Matrix B){
        this.MatrixToOperation = B.MatrixElem;
        for (int i=0;i<MatrixSize;i++){
            for (int j=0;j<MatrixSize;j++){
                for (int k=0;k<MatrixSize;k++){
                    MatrixElem[i][j] += MatrixElem[k][i] * MatrixToOperation[j][k];
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public double MatrixDeterminant(){
        MatrixDeterminant =
                  MatrixElem[0][0] * MatrixElem[1][1] * MatrixElem[2][2]
                + MatrixElem[1][0] * MatrixElem[2][1] * MatrixElem[0][2]
                + MatrixElem[0][1] * MatrixElem[1][2] * MatrixElem[2][0]

                -          (MatrixElem[2][0] * MatrixElem[1][1] * MatrixElem[0][2]
                          + MatrixElem[1][0] * MatrixElem[0][1] * MatrixElem[2][2]
                          + MatrixElem[1][2] * MatrixElem[2][1] * MatrixElem[0][0]);
        return MatrixDeterminant;
    }

    public double getMatrixDeterminant() {
        return MatrixDeterminant;
    }
    public void FindingAnEigenValue(Matrix A, Matrix SingleMatrix, Matrix DefaultMatrix){

        // Заполняем единичную матрицу
            SingleMatrix.setMatrixSingle();

        for (double Lymbda = 0; Lymbda <= 10; Lymbda+=0.00001){

            // 1. Умножаем единичную матрицу на констранту Lym
            // 2. Вычитаем из данной матрицы полученную матрицу

            SingleMatrix.MultiplyToConst(Lymbda);
            A.MatrixDiff(SingleMatrix);

            // 1. Находим определитель матрицы, после всех операций, если равен 0, выводим подходящее значение Lymbda

            if (A.MatrixDeterminant()==0){

                System.out.println(Lymbda);

            }

            // 1. Если цикл продолжается, возвращаем все значение в исходное состояние

            SingleMatrix.setMatrixSingle();
            A.MatrixDeterminant = 0;
            A = DefaultMatrix;
        }

    }
    public void setMatrixSingle(){
        for (int i=0;i<MatrixSize;i++){
            for (int j=0;j<MatrixSize;j++){
                if (i==j){
                    MatrixElem[i][j] = 1;
                }
                else {
                    MatrixElem[i][j] = 0;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. 
My matrix maths is basic but my first question, given you are calculating the determinate is can eigenvalue be calculated for all matrices. Second I would suggest starting with a small matrix and then expanding to your target matrix says. Good luck.